# XSL: Issue with str:split in for-each

Tags: xslt, split

Declaimer:  No data is real data, All the data is dummy including the tags but the logic is real.

The XML File

```
<MasterData>
<data>
    <document type="1"> <!-- Document 1 -->
        <configuration>
            <attribute_info>
                <attribute>Value similar to Document 2
                </attribute>
                <attribute>Value similar to Document 2
                </attribute>
            </attribute_info>
        </configuration>
        <Model>
            <Name>Products</Name>
            <ModelType>T1</ModelType>
        </Model>
    </document>
    <document type="2"> <!-- Document 2 -->
        <configuration>
            <attribute_info>
                <attribute name="shift" value="6$,$7$,$8$,$9$,$$,$$,$$,$" label="shift">6$,$7$,$8$,$9$,$$,$$,$$,$</attribute>
                <attribute name="serviceType" value="Replace$,$Standard Replace$,$Specific Replace$,$Bar Replace$,$Bar & Plate Replace$,$Bush Replace$,$Bush Replace - Standard$,$Bush Replace - Specific" label="serviceType">Replace$,$Standard Replace$,$Specific Replace$,$Bar Replace$,$Bar & Plate Replace$,$Bush Replace$,$Bush Replace - Standard$,$Bush Replace - Specific</attribute>
                <attribute name="hrs" value="1$,$2$,$2.5$,$4$,$1$,$2$,$6$,$6" label="hrs">1$,$2$,$2.5$,$4$,$1$,$2$,$6$,$6</attribute>
            </attribute_info>
        </configuration>
        <Model>
            <Name>Service</Name>
            <ModelType>T2</ModelType>
        </Model>
    </document>
    <document type="2"> <!-- Document 3 -->
        <configuration>
            <attribute_info>
                <attribute>Value similar to Document 2
                </attribute>
                <attribute>Value similar to Document 2
                </attribute>
            </attribute_info>
        </configuration>
        <Model>
            <Name>Service</Name>
            <ModelType>T2</ModelType>
        </Model>
    </document>
</data></MasterData>
```

The XSL File

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <Worksheet ss:Name="Excel Output Doc Mockup">
            <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="100" ss:ExpandedRowCount="600" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="42" ss:DefaultRowHeight="11.25">
                <xsl:for-each select="/MasterData/data/document[(normalize-space(./@type)='2') and (normalize-space(./Model/Name)='Service' and normalize-space(./Model/ModelType)='T2')]">

                    <xsl:variable name="shift" select="str:split(./configuration/attribute_info/attribute[@name='shift'],'$,$')" />
                    <xsl:variable name="hrs" select="str:split(./configuration/attribute_info/attribute[@name='hrs'],'$,$')" />

                    <xsl:for-each select="str:split(./configuration/attribute_info/attribute[@name='serviceType'],'$,$')">
                        <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
                            <Cell ss:Index="1">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:Index="2">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$shift[position()]"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <Cell ss:Index="3">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$hrs[position()]" />
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                        </Row>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Result in the excel workbook/worksheet

### Column1 Column2 Column3

Replace 6 1

Standard Replace 7 2

Specific Replace 8 2.5

Bar Replace 9 4

Bar & Plate Replace   1

Bush Replace   2

Bush Replace - Standard   6

Bush Replace - Specific   6

---

But i am getting the result as

### Column1 Column2 Column3

Replace 1 2

Standard Replace 2.5 4

Specific Replace 1 2

Bar Replace 6 6

Bar & Plate Replace

Bush Replace

Bush Replace - Standard

Bush Replace - Specific

It seems like I am getting the values of the latest split string even though I refer to the respective split strings using their respective variables.

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$shift[position()]"/>
```

**Do**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$shift[$vPos+0]"/>
```

and have `$vPos` defined immediately after the `xsl:for-each`:

```
<xsl:for-each select=
  "str:split(./configuration/attribute_info/attribute[@name='serviceType'],'$,$')">

  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
```

**Remember**: 
  The `position()` function is context-sensitive.

Its value in;

```
<xsl:value-of select="$shift[position()]"/>
```

is *not* the position of `current()` in the current node-list.

Comment: +1 for the context comment - this is a hard concept for some to get and is all important in xsl

Comment: @Dimitre...I have tried that also which was not giving the desired result.

Comment: @Bugude: You have to explain what exactly the transformation should do -- then many people could give you a correct solution. We *don't* know what you want to achieve. I have uncovered just one problem in your code and you are confirming that there are others, too.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I am trying to pull out the data from the XML (similar to the example one above) and create a excel workbook and populate the data as table (header, data).